# BigQuery of database

Tags: python, syntax, google-bigquery

I have written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
QUERY = """
    SELECT provider_city, provider_state, drg_definition, average_total_payments, 
    average_medicare_payments
    FROM 'bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_charges_2015'
    WHERE provider_city = "GREAT FALLS" AND provider_state = "MT"
    ORDER BY provider_city ASC
    LIMIT 1000
    """
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('MedicareProject-xxxxxxxxxxxx.json')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)
df = query_job.to_dataframe()
print ("Records Returned: ", df.shape )
print ()
print ("First 3 Records")
print (df.head(3))
```

I am getting this error:

lib\site-packages\google\api_core\future\polling.py", line 130, in result
raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_char...' at [3:10]

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

```
'bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_charges_2015'
```

You should use back-ticks instead as in below exampple

```
`bigquery-public-data.cms_medicare.inpatient_charges_2015`
```